# Gitlab CI: create dist folder inside repository?

Tags: npm, continuous-integration, gitlab

I just recently started using gitlab CI to automate some build/deploy steps. It works perfectly to build docker images etc, but I was wondering if it's possible to create a folder in the repository during a build step? For example I'm now making an npm utility package, but I'm just importing it in my other projects via a private gitlab repo (using deploy token), but the code of the util package is written in es6 and needs to be transpiled to commonJS to be used in the other packages. Manually I can run *npm run build* and it will output a dist folder with the transpiled code.

I was trying (and researching) if it's possible to automate this build process using .gitlab-ci but so far I couldn't find anything.

Anyone know how I can achieve this and/or if this is possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I got your question correctly, so add more details if not.

When your CI build creates new folders or files, they are written to the task runner's file system (no surprise here, I assume).

If you want to access these files from Gitlab's web UI you can define them as **artifacts** in your build job (see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.html)

Your build job would look something like that (pseudo code written by memory, not tested on Gitlab):

```
build:
  script:
  - npm run build
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - dist/
    expire_in: 1 week
```

---

**UPDATE** If you want to upload the build artifact to an NPM registry, you could just build and push together.

```
build:
  script:
  - npm run build
  - npm publish <PARAMETERS>
```

Comment: I meant in the repository itself, so on each push, I would like to have a dist folder created in the repository, since I use the whole repo as an npm package in other services, but I love to use the latest es standards, so I need to transpile with Babel. But I understand that this is not possible, but instead I need something like a precommit hook instead of a CI command, but +1 for this solution since this is also a way to achieve something similar.

Comment: Hi @JC97, thx for the credit ;)
By creating a folder inside the repository, do you mean to `git commit & git push` the folder? Well, this would _a)_ trigger a new build pipe line and _b)_ store build artifacts inside the repo. I'd avoid both. That is what build pipelines and _artifacts_ are designed for. The last step of your pipeline would be the `npm publish` to the registry. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: I see what you mean, didn't knew how though, now I do :) I'll just trial with the precommit hook for now, but if I have the need in the future, I'll use a private npm registry. Thanks!

Comment: To clarify you can also use (in yaml syntax) as per `.gitlab-ci.yaml`
`cache: -> paths: -> -> - dist/`, and the folder will be maintained through the stages so, as describe by @KonstantinA.Magg you can publish you package.