# Vue.js build on Gitlab CI/CD not producing any artifacts in `/dist` directory

Tags: vue.js, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm attempting to add a `build` stage to my CI/CD pipeline that I'm running on Gitlab.com. The build seemingly 'completes' without error, but the `/dist` directory remains empty after the build.

Here's the relevant config from my `gitlab-ci.yml` file:

[image]

But the result as seen in the runner logs is an empty `/dist` directory:

[image]

The runner reports that it `found one matching files`, but I'm assuming that it's counting the empty `/dist` dir as the file that it found because the directory itself is empty, which causes my `deploy` stage to fail when it tries to upload the missing artifacts.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

The build seems to succeed just fine, but there's no resulting files in the `/dist` directory. And with that in mind, where are they going then?

I've tried many different representations of the path, and even tried utilizing the `process.env.CI_PROJECT_DIR` var as the value in my webpack.config file(s) but I can't get the artifacts to land in the `/dist` dir.

When I download the artifacts .zip file using the Gitlab.com console I just end up with an empty folder.

Thanks in advance for any light anyone can shed on this.

Comment: Do you see any logs for the `npm run build` command? Maybe it failed to build..? Usually, I get this problem when the env does not have the proper packages installed in node_modules, so `npm run build` fails, but Gitlab CI doesn't treat it as failed.

Comment: @GinoMempin Excellent question. I've been assuming that the build succeeds because there's no indication of failure in the runner logs. I'll investigate that closer. It shouldn't be an issue with any of the node_modules because those are all checked-in to my repo. I'll try with `npm i` and see what results I get.

Comment: @GinoMempin Bingo. That was it. Thank you very much. I was going out of my mind with this one. It must have been an environment issue with one of the node modules (OSX vs Ubuntu). I zorked the `node_modules` folder and added `npm install` and everything worked as expected. If you post the above as an answer I'll choose it as correct.

Comment: Are you sure that build command will build all assets into the dist folder? As I see you have to artifacts the build folder instead of dist folder.

Comment: @AliTorki Nope. The `build` folder is where the build.js files are stored. This is how a typical Vue.js project is organized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably nothing wrong with the `artifacts` creation, but there could be something wrong with the `npm run build` part of the job. I usually get this problem when `npm run build` fails (for example, the CI env does not have the proper packages installed in *node_modules*), so nothing gets put under the *dist* folder. The problem is that Gitlab CI **will not abort the job** when `npm run build` fails, and it would still continue up to the `artifacts` creation, which as you reported, will zip-up an empty *dist* folder.

Check that the `npm run build` part of the job actually succeeds.

Comment: As noted in a comment above, this is the correct answer. The problem was that the `npm run build` command was *not* succeeding, but the runner logs didn't provide any indication that it had failed (which is to say that the job continued to progress even after the build step had failed).

Comment: The specific issue in my case was that my `node_modules` folder was checked-in to my repo (on purpose), but there were issues with some modules not running on Ubuntu as they do on OSX (my local build env). Adding `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm install` before the `npm run build` step fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about npm running on gitlab ci, but it may be what you need.
[Gitlab CI: create dist folder inside repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54343180/gitlab-ci-create-dist-folder-inside-repository)